# Regex in .net finding all occurances after a certain string

Tags: regex

Very new to regexp. I want to match all occurrences of a string which occurs after a certain pattern but I am not able to come up with a regex to do that (in .net).

The string looks something like this:

```
MAIN SKUID="AAAAAA" any number of characters here  AdHocID="123456" some characters AdHocID="856322224" ..some chars again etc.....
```

I want to find all ooccurances of "AdHocID=digits (including the quotation marks) " only if there is a

`MAIN SKUID="AAAAAA"` somewhere before. If SKUID is not AAAAAA then I don't need those AdhocID strings.

Currently I am using regex pattern

```
(?<= SKUID="AAAAAA" )(?:.*)AdHocID={d,} .*
```

I searched through the threads and tried some patterns with no luck

Comment: Could you please also specify the expected output? It is not 100% clear if you want to get `AdHocID="856322224"` in the result, too. Also, if you have access to the code, it might be more efficient to first get the position of the substring you want to start searching from and pass that index to the regex matching method. And could you please re-check if you really have `{d,}` in your code? What do you want to match with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the `.*` part to the lookbehind which is supported in .NET.

To match the digits you should use `\d+`. Using curly braces that would look like `\d{1,}`

```
(?<=SKUID="AAAAAA" .*)\bAdHocID="\d+"
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dSKUID%3d%22AAAAAA%22+.*%29%5cbAdHocID%3d%22%5cd%2b%22&i=MAIN+SKUID%3d%22AAAAAA%22+any+number+of+characters+here+AdHocID%3d%22123456%22+some+characters+AdHocID%3d%22856322224%22+..some+chars+again+etc)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the lookbehind you can also make use of continuous matching by using the `\G` token, like

```
(?:\G(?!^)|SKUID="AAAAAA").*?\b(AdHocID="\d+")
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5CG%28%3F!%5E%29%7CSKUID%3D%22AAAAAA%22%29.*%3F%5Cb%28AdHocID%3D%22%5Cd%2B%22%29&i=MAIN%20SKUID%3D%22AAAAAA%22%20any%20number%20of%20characters%20here%20%20AdHocID%3D%22123456%22%20some%20characters%20AdHocID%3D%22856322224%22%20..some%20chars%20again%20etc.....)